# Hibernate @TypeDef creating 1000 typeclass instances

Tags: java, hibernate

I got all my entities annotated with `@TypeDef` which is actually trimming the String result from the database using a `TrimClass`. When I done the profiling I could find there are more than `1000 active objects` in the memory and survived many garbage collection. I just need a singelton object here. since this is controlled by Hibernate I dont know how to fix this issue.